# Jquery on image error not working on dynamic images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js code,

```
 $(document).on("error", "img", function () {
            alert('a')
            this.src = ResolveUrl("~/images/tree-item.png");
        });
```

This event is not triggered. I am sure there are lot of broken images

Comment: where is ResolveUrl() code?

Comment: It's a client side function. Even I remove it the alert is not triggering

Comment: I'm not sure you can work make event delegation on `document` using the `error` event. This event won't bubble to the document object if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Itay, the document is the container for testing, the target is img element

Comment: Then how to make it dynamic images to work with error. @Itay

Comment: I think the only way is to use normal `$("img").on("error", etc` on the document onLoad and then add this handler to every image you're adding to the DOM.

Comment: Do you even need it to work on dynamically added images?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37013/discussion-between-itay-and-user960567)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use `event delegation` for the `error` event on the document object, because unlike other events (such as `onclick`), the `onerror` event isn't being bubbled to the document object.

Use normal event binding instead:

```
$('img').on("error", function () {
    this.src = ResolveUrl("~/images/tree-item.png");
});
```

- P.S - This will work only on the images that are already on the DOM when this command is executed.

---

To handle dynamically added images as well, you need to attach this event to every image you add to the DOM. Here's an example:

```
function handleError() {
    this.src = ResolveUrl("~/images/tree-item.png");
}

// Bind the event to the existing images on the DOM when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').on("error", handleError);
}

// An example for a function that adds images dynamically
function addImage(imgSource, destination) {
    var newImg = $("img").on("error", handleError)
                         .attr("src", imgSource);

    $(destination).append(newImg);
}
```

Comment: Attaching the handler should be done before defining the source attribute.

Answer (score 10):

I know, its an old question, but maybe someone is looking for a better solution:

```
// The function to insert a fallback image
var imgNotFound = function() {
    $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "/path/to/fallback/img.jpg");
};
// Bind image error on document load
$("img").error(imgNotFound);
// Bind image error after ajax complete
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("img").error(imgNotFound);
});
```

This code attaches the error-event listener to the img tag on body load and after every ajax call.

Comment: works great. For newer jquery, use `$('img').on('error', imgNotFound)`

Answer (score 1):

This can done without jQuery by using event delegation during the capturing phase.

```js
document.addEventListener('error', e => {
    // e.target is the element that had the error event
    // to check if the element is an img element: if (e.target.matches('img'))
    e.target.src = 'default.png';
}, true);
```

Comment: Wow, never realised could use capture phase when bubbling is not available. This also works great when appending whole blocks of html to the page containing image tags, eg. when loading content via ajax.