# How to listen to the error event of all images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, events

I want to hide broken images that get loaded dynamically. For static ones, this works.

```
$('img').error(function() {
    $(this).css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
});
```

However, when I bind that to the `document` nothing happens. There is no error in the console, either.

```
$(document).on('error', 'img', function() {
    $(this).css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
});
```

How can I listen to errors of images that are loaded dynamically?

Comment: it is because the [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/error) event does not bubbles.. and delegated handler such as the one you have tried depends on the event being bubbled to the ancestor document element

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery on image error not working on dynamic images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683503/jquery-on-image-error-not-working-on-dynamic-images)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/error) event does **not** *bubble*. The [DOM Level 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) specifies it should but [The DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-error) overrides this.

<strike>You could try `window.onerror` but I'm not sure if that only catches *run-time script errors* in your code or errors thrown by failing resources. If it works it will also catch all errors.</strike>

Arun P Johny confirms my doubts, `window.onerror` is a no-go.

The matter is discussed in [error event with live](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/error-event-with-live).

A solution could be to add a generic error handler on all images, those loaded dynamicly included. And then have that generic error handler trigger a custom jQuery event, e.g.:

```
$( document ).on( 'imgerror', function ( event, originalEvent ) {
    // originalEvent is the error event
} );

function genericImgOnError( event ) {
    $( event.target ).trigger( 'imgerror', event );
}

function getImg( src ) {
    return $( '<img/>', {
        src: src,
    } ).on( 'error', genericImgOnError );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So there is no solution to this? I'll use `setInterval` then to apply error handlers to all current images every second or so. Does my event handler gets called even if the image already failed to load some milliseconds ago?

Comment: No, the event must be added before the error event triggers. You can read about it at http://api.jquery.com/error/

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with the `useCapture` of `addEventListener`.

```
document.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
  // do your magic here
}, true)
```

Comment: I tried. It does not seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/onhL16k0/