# Load default image when error dynamic image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need to load a default image in the event that the image is broken. This also needs to apply to dynamic images. Always limited by class.

I found a similar question [Jquery on image error not working on dynamic images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683503/jquery-on-image-error-not-working-on-dynamic-images) but it doesn't seem to work for dynamic images in my case

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/sb8303aq/1/

```
$('img.myClass').on("error", function () {
    this.src = 'http://placehold.it/150x150&text=PLACEHOLDER';
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $('body').append('<img src="http://image_doesn-t_exist_url" class="myClass" />');
});
```

Comment: demo's error function just run once.

Comment: @lsv it runs on page load and then errors when adding an image via the button

Answer (score 0):

you can put error function into append function.

```js
$('img.myClass').on("error", function () {
    this.src = 'http://placehold.it/150x150&text=PLACEHOLDER';
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $('body').append('<img src="http://image_doesn-t_exist_url" class="myClass" />');
    $('img').on("error", function () {
    this.src = 'http://placehold.it/150x150&text=PLACEHOLDER';
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=img%20loaded" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=img%20loaded" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=img%20loaded" />
<img src="http://image_doesn-t_exist_url" class='myClass' />

<p>
<button>
Add Image
</button>
</p>
```