# jquery event is not firing on appended elements even using .on()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace the image when it encounters error on the initial src by using this...

```
$(".thumbnails").on("error", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("src") != "/assets/img/img-error.jpg") {
        $(this).attr("src", "/assets/img/img-error.jpg");
    }
});
```

It's working fine on images that has been loaded during page load..however when I got images appended in a `modal` or `popover` it didn't trigger the function even though I'm using .on() delegation

I also tried using this but it didn't do the function even on images during page load..

```
$(document).on("error", ".thumbnails", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("src") != "/assets/img/img-error.jpg") {
        $(this).attr("src", "/assets/img/img-error.jpg");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try: `$(document).on("error", ".thumbnails", function () {}` if your DOM elements are not there at run time and added dynamically then they wont be attached to the event.

Comment: @Bossman I tried using that but the event did not fire at all even on elements on load o_O weird..

Comment: You need attach the event handler when you append the image to the appended elements. @RoryMcCrossan error event don't bubble so you can't use it for event delegation.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683503/jquery-on-image-error-not-working-on-dynamic-images/18683695

Comment: @MarkBaijens very good point, duplicate updated

Comment: Thanks @Bossman it worked on images I appended on modals.. now my only problem is the images returned in popover..I'm returning more images when hovering on that thumbnails on page load using bootstrap popover..is there any way to attach event handler for popover image?

Comment: ah, I found a solution to attach event handler on popover contents by using  `$(document).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {});` Thanks for the help guys! :)